# List all values from column B and count distinct values in column A which have at least one record with corresponding A and B

Tags: sql

List all values from column B and count distinct values in column A which have at least one record with corresponding A and B

```
File name | File extension
--------------------------
100011    | txt
100011    | pdf
100017    | txt
100017    | pdf
100017    | txt
100018    | pdf
100018    | xls
```

Expected result

```
txt       | 2
pdf       | 3
xls       | 1
```

Answer (score 2):

use distinct count

```
 select fileextension,count( distinct filename) from table
 group by fileextension
```

Comment: You need to use `distinct` : `count(distinct filename)`